# Strange 404 error on local host

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

So I have a mySQL database and i have it hooked up to some php and html files. My php file is in the localhost folder. When i run my test html file which is also in my localhost folder, it has no problem finding the file, but when i have a subfolder within my localhost folder called "SriMeru" where i have my actual html file with formatting and other things along with the final php file, the html file cannot locate the php file. Here's some code in the html file:

```
<div id="mmargin" style="background-color:#F1ECDF;height:810px;width:600px;float:left;">
      <p id = "myDiv">no</p>
   <script>
       function loadPHPDoc(str){
       var xmlhttp;
       if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
         {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
         xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
         }
       else
         {// code for IE6, IE5
         xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
         }
       xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
         {
         if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
           {
           document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
           }
         else{
           document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML="failure";
         }
         }
       xmlhttp.open("POST","srimeru/forumSubmit.php",true);
       xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
       var sender = "q=" + str;
       xmlhttp.send(sender);
       }

   </script>

      <p>
     Message <input type= "text" id="messbox">
     <button type= "button" onclick="loadPHPDoc(document.getElementById('messbox').value)">input</button>
      </p>
</div>
```

and here's my php file code:

```
<?php

    $q = $_POST["q"];

    $messData = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "chendu", "SriMeru");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
        echo "Failed to connect to Server";
    }
    $sql = "INSERT INTO messages VALUES ('".$q."')";
    mysqli_query($messData, $sql);
    echo "<p>success</p>";

   mysqli_close($messData);
?>
```

Other places in the html file, i have some weird formatting involving marquee and timers, i dont know if this could mess things up.

Comment: side note: general opinion any one using `marquee` should be taken out back and shot.

Comment: I got it all working, thanks. Excuse the marquee, this is my first time ever making a website.

Comment: What's the difference between a "strange" 404 error and a "normal" 404 error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *"but when i have a subfolder within my localhost folder called **"SriMeru"** where i have my actual html file"*

You say your folder is named `SriMeru`

On many systems (including UNIX/LINUX), `SriMeru` and `srimeru` are not the same thing; they are case-sensitive.

Therefore, either rename your folder to be all in lowercase letters, or change `srimeru/forumSubmit.php` to `SriMeru/forumSubmit.php`

Comment: @ChristianColomb You're welcome Christian. I'm curious to know what it was though.